# Can't get timings right with transitions fade in and out

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I can't seem to get the timings right on my transitions:

I want each item to nicely fade in, then stay visible for 5 seconds then nicely fade out to the next item, and repeat. And on an infinite loop (which is working)

```css
@keyframes fadeinout {
  0% { opacity: 0; },
  6% { opacity: 1; },
  34% { opacity: 1; },
  40% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

.e {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.one {
  background: red;
  animation: fadeinout 3s infinite 1s;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  animation: fadeinout 3s infinite 2s;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
  animation: fadeinout 3s infinite 3s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li class="e one">item one</li>
  <li class="e two">item two</li>
  <li class="e three">item three</li>
</ul>
```

See this CodePen: https://codepen.io/pbul2004/pen/zYOjzRa

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @TylerH I tried to submit an edit but so far it's been rejected, even though I pretty much copied the code from the codepen ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @GammaGames That's probably because it's (often) a violation of licensing to copy someone else's code from JSFiddle or CodePen (which provide no license guidance) over to Stack Overflow (which licenses code under CC-By SA 3.0 (or 4.0 if you're OK with that)). In many cases the code is insufficient to be licensed, though, so it's not a clear-cut case every time.

Comment: @GammaGames Also, you should always *leave* the link to the external code sandbox in the post; don't remove it just because the code is in the question now. Some people do find it easier to jump into a JSFiddle or CodePen to work with OP's code.

Comment: Highly recommend checking this presentation out http://slides.com/davidkhourshid/deck-17#/9 The author created a mixin to do this kind of keyframe math automatically.

Comment: @TylerH Ah, I hadn't realized you should leave the link, the rejection reason was a generic "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First include the "stay" mode in the keyframes so the element remains visible for 5 seconds, and secondly add 5 seconds of delay to each animation why applying animation property.

```css
.e {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%, 40% { opacity: 0; }
  6%, 34% { opacity: 1; }  /* "stay" mode */ 
}
.one {
  background:red;
  animation: fadeinout 15s infinite 1s;
}
.two {
  background:green;
  animation: fadeinout 15s infinite 6s; /* Offset */
}
.three {
  background:yellow;
  animation: fadeinout 15s infinite 11s; /* Offset */
}
```

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li class="e one">item one</li>
  <li class="e two">item two</li>
  <li class="e three">item three</li>
</ul>
```

The visible mode of each item will come during the hidden mode of the two others. Once understood the idea, you can fine tune the durations and delays :) ( for instance I overlapped the fades on purpose )

Comment: You can also use one opacity value for multiple percents in the keyframes, like `6%, 34% { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: I've tried adding your suggestions to the codepen, and it still seems to be the same, flashing up very fast?

Comment: did you tried the code snippet button under my answer ? Is it not what you want ?